# Bounty September competition

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, fun, competitions, bounties

I propose we use some bounties during September to reduce the [number of unanswered questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered).

So if you want in, post your name in its own answer below.  The idea being that you want to have the most bounties in September.

To achieve:

- Post up to 3 bounties at a time (system limit) on unanswered questions. Link to them in your answer below.
- When an upvoted answer (posted AFTER you posted this bounty) appears on a question that you feel warrants a bounty (after all it's your bounty to spend), spend the bounty.
- Post new bounty, and repeat.

The winner will be the person who posted the most number of (not value of) bounties during the month of September ([UTC time](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current%20time%20utc)).

Since we have almost two weeks before it starts, sign up now to commit, and comments on possible rule adjustments below.

**RESULTS**:

1. Mark Mayo - 25
2. JonathanReez - 22
3. Relaxed - 12
4. JoErNanO - 9
5. Gayot Fow - 3
6. Nean Der Thal - 2

Winner: **Mark Mayo**

Comment: @GayotFow there is no bounty button because the question is new. AFAIK you can add a bounty 48 hours after the question has been asked. See http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/bounty

Comment: ## JoErNanO

1. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51052/receiving-a-compensation-from-sncf-after-missing-ferry-due-to-delayed-train

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Mark Mayo

Bounties added for this month: **25**

1. [Domestic-domestic at Manchester, UK: any security to clear?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52740/domestic-domestic-at-manchester-uk-any-security-to-clear)
2. [Canada to India via Germany on Expired Canadian Visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51527/canada-to-india-via-germany-on-expired-canadian-visa)
3. [Does the cancellation of my wife's US visa at the point of entry affect mine?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52231/does-the-cancellation-of-my-wifes-us-visa-at-the-point-of-entry-affect-mine)
4. [Minimum connection times at YUL, allowing for US pre-clearance](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53533/minimum-connection-times-at-yul-allowing-for-us-pre-clearance)
5. [Why does Ryanair check non-EU passengers' visas on intra-Schengen and domestic flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/54014/why-does-ryanair-check-non-eu-passengers-visas-on-intra-schengen-and-domestic-f)
6. [Where is it expected to tip housekeeping?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48379/where-is-it-expected-to-tip-housekeeping)
7. [Use United Airlines travel certificate for another passenger?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51395/use-united-airlines-travel-certificate-for-another-passenger)
8. [German entering USA from Mexico after loss of passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47860/german-entering-usa-from-mexico-after-loss-of-passport)
9. [What's the fastest way of getting a visa for Australia after ETA is refused?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50960/whats-the-fastest-way-of-getting-a-visa-for-australia-after-eta-is-refused)
10. [Will Amtrak honor a saver ticket from an earlier station when other saver tickets are sold out?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46810/will-amtrak-honor-a-saver-ticket-from-an-earlier-station-when-other-saver-ticket)
11. [Taking 2 laptops and an iPad for travel, as a student, to South Korea from USA](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51939/taking-2-laptops-and-an-ipad-for-travel-as-a-student-to-south-korea-from-usa)
12. [What are the options when my UAE visa was issued one day short of intended trip duration?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49666/what-are-the-options-when-my-uae-visa-was-issued-one-day-short-of-intended-trip)
13. [What is the best way to transport a large bike pack and two suitcases from Heathrow to Pinner?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50930/what-is-the-best-way-to-transport-a-large-bike-pack-and-two-suitcases-from-heath)
14. [How much should I tip for a private tour in India?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50035/how-much-should-i-tip-for-a-private-tour-in-india)
15. [Can I visit the US for tourism on a previously unused B1/B2 visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/54259/can-i-visit-the-us-for-tourism-on-a-previously-unused-b1-visa)
16. [Contain the Georgian Triangle and Southwestern Ontario any 'drive-through' parks or wildlife areas?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/55496/do-the-georgian-triangle-and-southwestern-ontario-contain-any-drive-through-w)
17. [Is advance booking required for ferries from China to South Korea?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47262/is-advance-booking-required-for-ferries-from-china-to-south-korea)
18. [Firstname and Lastname confusion while ticket booking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52729/firstname-and-lastname-confusion-while-ticket-booking)
19. [Proof of funds for a UK citizen visiting Canada for 5 months](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49902/proof-of-funds-for-a-uk-citizen-visiting-canada-for-5-months)
20. [What does the first line in an Galileo itinerary mean?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56342/what-does-the-first-line-in-an-galileo-itinerary-mean)
21. [Assuming I have Irish car insurance, do I need to buy extra coverage when renting a car in Portugal?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50664/assuming-i-have-irish-car-insurance-do-i-need-to-buy-extra-coverage-when-rentin)
22. [Can I ask for a luggage transfer at the transfer check in counter in Taipei?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44020/can-i-ask-for-a-luggage-transfer-at-the-transfer-check-in-counter-in-taipei)
23. [Is there a difference in insurance coverage when booking cars through Priceline/Hotwire, rather than booking directly on the rental company's website?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47510/is-there-a-difference-in-insurance-coverage-when-booking-cars-through-priceline)
24. [Do I need a return flight for all airlines to go to Argentina?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56616/do-i-need-a-return-flight-for-all-airlines-to-go-to-argentina)
25. [Turkish visa processing still ongoing after the date of my intended trip has passed. What can I do?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48553/turkish-visa-processing-still-ongoing-after-the-date-of-my-intended-trip-has-pas)

Comment: You show off! I'm coming to get you.

Answer (score 3):

### JoErNanO

Bounties this month: **9**

1. [Receiving a compensation from SNCF after missing ferry due to delayed train](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51052/receiving-a-compensation-from-sncf-after-missing-ferry-due-to-delayed-train)
2. [Orthopedic medical tourism in Cuba?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51092/orthopedic-medical-tourism-in-cuba)
3. [Getting from Salt Lake City airport to Park City by public transport on a weekend night](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48987/getting-from-salt-lake-city-airport-to-park-city-by-public-transport-on-a-weeken)
4. [Can a foreigner get a visa for China in Taiwan?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53961/can-a-foreigner-get-a-visa-for-china-in-taiwan)
5. [Extend maximum duration of stay for a multi-entry Chinese visa (Q2)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51475/extend-maximum-duration-of-stay-for-a-multi-entry-chinese-visa-q2)
6. [I am an Indian Permanent Resident of the US. I've lost my passport in India. What are the steps to replace it?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/54333/i-am-an-indian-permanent-resident-of-the-us-ive-lost-my-passport-in-india-wha)
7. [Under what conditions can I take duty free liquids from outside the EU through EU airport security?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52301/under-what-conditions-can-i-take-duty-free-liquids-from-outside-the-eu-through-e)
8. [What supporting documents do I need to bring on a trip to the US on a previously used B1/B2 visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51005/what-supporting-documents-do-i-need-to-bring-on-a-trip-to-the-us-on-a-previously)
9. [Throat singing lessons in Mongolia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22379/throat-singing-lessons-in-mongolia)

Other useless blabla so that the system accepts my answer.

Answer (score 3):

### Nean Der Thal

1. [Is it easier for a westerner to obtain a Chinese tourist visa in Kazakhstan or Kyrgyzstan?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52778/is-it-easier-for-a-westerner-to-obtain-a-chinese-tourist-visa-in-kazakhstan-or-k)
2. [Casual Khmer language classes or language exchange in Siem Reap?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42967/casual-khmer-language-classes-or-interchange-in-siem-reap)

I will be adding more later...

Answer (score 2):

### Relaxed

Bounties added thus far: 12

1. [Avoiding crowded times in southern Utah national parks and monuments](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48974/avoiding-crowded-times-in-southern-utah-national-parks-and-monuments)
2. [Supplying your own needle for Blood test for a Kurdistan residency permit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42666/supplying-your-own-needle-for-blood-test-for-a-kurdistan-residency-permit)
3. [Is advance booking required for ferries from China to South Korea?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47262/is-advance-booking-required-for-ferries-from-china-to-south-korea)
4. [Visa for Istanbul trip during layover](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53189/visa-for-istanbul-trip-during-layover)
5. [Do I need to include details about a side trip to another country on my Schengen application form?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49997/do-i-need-to-including-details-about-a-side-trip-to-another-country-on-my-scheng)
6. [Getting from Salt Lake City airport to Park City by public transport on a weekend night](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48987/getting-from-salt-lake-city-airport-to-park-city-by-public-transport-on-a-weeken)
7. [Where can I find a ski touring guide book for the Patagonia region?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52002/ski-touring-guide-book-for-patagonia)
8. [Long layover at Copenhagen Airport (CPH)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52788/long-layover-at-copenhagen-airport-cph)
9. [Entering the UK with an expired EU passport and a valid non-EU passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52051/entering-the-uk-with-an-expired-eu-passport-and-a-valid-non-eu-passport)
10. [Is there some way to find the cheapest airline tickets for a lot of countries](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/54284/is-there-some-way-to-find-most-cheapest-airline-tickets-for-a-lot-of-countries)
11. [Overstaying a tourist visa in Cambodia: what are the penalties and bureaucratic hurdles involved?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53911/overstaying-a-tourist-visa-in-cambodia-what-are-the-penalties-and-bureaucratic)
12. [Is there some way to find the cheapest airline tickets for a lot of countries](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/54284/is-there-some-way-to-find-most-cheapest-airline-tickets-for-a-lot-of-countries)

Answer (score 2):

### Gayot

1. [Visa processing speed: VFS vs Embassy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53464/visa-processing-speed-vfs-vs-embassy)
2. [Belarus visa application](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53813/belarus-visa-application)
3. [Meeting young people in Mongolia, especially outside UB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51677/meeting-young-people-in-mongolia-especially-outside-ub)

**Adding...**

Non-contest bounty added for this one: [How to intentionally get denied entry to the US, without getting into trouble?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24540/how-to-intentionally-get-denied-entry-to-the-us-without-getting-into-trouble) please help elevate and keep near the top of views/votes/active lists.

Answer (score 2):

### JonathanReez

Bounties added for this month: **22**

1. [Will Amtrak honor a saver ticket from an earlier station when other saver tickets are sold out?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46810/will-amtrak-honor-a-saver-ticket-from-an-earlier-station-when-other-saver-ticket)
2. [Do US citizens need to purchase US health insurance while traveling abroad, under the rules of the Affordable Care Act?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47515/do-us-citizens-need-to-purchase-us-health-insurance-while-traveling-abroad-unde)
3. [What is the daily fee for using a local SIM card in Cuba?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51142/what-is-the-daily-fee-for-using-a-local-sim-card-in-cuba)
4. [Transiting from the US through the UK on a Child Visitor visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51015/transiting-from-the-us-through-the-uk-on-a-child-visitor-visa)
5. [How to get from Flores to Sulawesi?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49720/how-to-get-from-flores-to-sulawesi)
6. [How recent should my bank statement be when applying for a Schengen visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50539/how-recent-should-my-bank-statement-be-when-applying-for-a-bulgarian-visa)
7. [Can I use a Transit UK Visa to visit London, while in transit between Frankfurt and Paris?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49230/using-a-transit-uk-visa-to-visit-london-while-in-transit-between-frankfurt-and)
8. [Data-only sim-card for a 1-week stay in Hungary](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49953/data-only-sim-card-for-a-1-week-stay-in-hungary)
9. [I work in the US on an H1-B visa and will apply for a Schengen visa soon. Will my Schengen visa be affected if I switch to a US student visa later on?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48287/i-work-in-the-us-on-an-h1-b-visa-and-will-apply-for-a-schengen-visa-soon-later)
10. [Applying for a UK visitor visa in India after receiving a UK visa refusal in Saudi Arabia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50912/applying-for-a-uk-visitor-visa-in-india-after-receiving-a-uk-visa-refusal-in-sau)
11. [Proving ties to your home country when applying for a German visa as a non-employed Russian citizen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51589/proving-ties-to-your-home-country-when-applying-for-a-german-visa-as-a-non-emplo)
12. [Minimum connection time at Frankfurt Airport for an International to Schengen transit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52311/minimum-connection-time-at-frankfurt-airport-for-an-international-to-schengen-tr)
13. [Can I receive a UAE transit visa after entering the country on a tourist visa within the last 30 days?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49610/can-i-receive-a-uae-transit-visa-after-entering-the-country-on-a-tourist-visa-wi)
14. [Entering the Schengen area 12 days before my visa expires](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50433/entering-the-schengen-area-12-days-before-my-visa-expires)
15. [What's the fastest way of getting a visa for Australia after ETA is refused?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50960/whats-the-fastest-way-of-getting-a-visa-for-australia-after-eta-is-refused)
16. [Using American's Admiral Lounge when I have a ticket from Gulf Air on an American-operated flight](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56030/using-americans-admiral-lounge-when-i-have-a-ticket-from-gulf-air-on-an-america)
17. [How can I confirm that my I-94 form was correctly processed after leaving the US in 2007?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48273/how-can-i-confirm-that-my-i-94-form-was-correctly-processed-after-leaving-the-us)
18. [Turkish visa processing still ongoing after the date of my intended trip has passed. What can I do?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48553/turkish-visa-processing-still-ongoing-after-the-date-of-my-intended-trip-has-pas)
19. [Can I get a multi-entry Schengen visa if travelling to two different countries on two separate trips?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/55729/can-i-get-a-multi-entry-schengen-visa-from-french-embassy-if-i-am-travelling-to)
20. [Do I need a pre-paid hotel reservation to apply for a Schengen visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56111/pre-paid-or-free-cancellation-hotel-reservation-for-schengen-visa)
21. [Apps to walk me through Frankfurt Germany](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53417/apps-to-walk-me-through-frankfurt-germany)
22. [What supporting documents do I need to bring on a trip to the US on a previously used B1/B2 visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51005/what-supporting-documents-do-i-need-to-bring-on-a-trip-to-the-us-on-a-previously)

Other useless blabla so that the system accepts my answer. Another useless blabla so that the system accepts my answer. Did I mention I need more blabla.

Comment: Blabla. Blabla.

Comment: I'm very proud of your commitment.

Comment: Great effort, it was very close in the end!

Comment: @MarkMayo for three glorious days I was ahead! See you next year ;)